# How can I focus or change label color on mouse-hover in Timeline Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have data like this:

```
var data = [{
    x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
    name: 'First dogs in space',
    label: 'fds',
    dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: false,
        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
            '</span><br/>{point.label}'
    },
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite',
    label: 'First artificial satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
    label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
    name: 'First human spaceflight',
    label: 'First human spaceflight',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
    name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
    label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
    name: 'First human on the Moon',
    label: 'First human on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19),
    name: 'First space station',
    label: 'First space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
    name: 'First soft Mars landing',
    label: 'First soft Mars landing',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
    name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
    label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1978, 11, 4),
    name: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
    label: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1986, 1, 19),
    name: 'First inhabited space station',
    label: 'First inhabited space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
    name: 'First astrometric satellite',
    label: 'First astrometric satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
    name: 'First multinational space station',
    label: 'First multinational space station',
}];
```

Here is the fiddle link for your reference:[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urchwqsk/)

In which what I want i.e while mouse-hover on labels its changes it's color or maybe focused so that I can easily understand my pointer is one x label.

I have tried `shadow` in Plotoption, Series and In Datalabel but didn't work.

You can see the reference here [API Highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/9pfwjrct/)

[Exampler API Highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/jzcwb3vn/4/)

Comment: Do you want to highlight columns or labels? Here an example with xAxis labels: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d438aeh5/. To change column color use https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.states.hover

Comment: @WojciechChmiel yes I want to highlight labels in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the labels in the timeline series you can add this code to the chart load event:

```
chart: {
  type: 'timeline',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;

      chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
        point.dataLabel.on('mouseover', function() {
          point.dataLabel.box.css({
            fill: 'red'
          });
        });

        point.dataLabel.on('mouseout', function() {
          point.dataLabel.box.css({
            fill: 'white'
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wc83q6j4/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Answer (score 0):

There is states option available, where you can set the color of bar on hover state

> for more info follow the link below
>
> > https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.states.hover.color

check Demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/s15cu4xp/)**

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column',
        states: {
               hover: {
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    borderColor: '#FF0000'
                }
         }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Jyoti -  This method is not working in my example which is the Timeline chart.